# Can't run ride.py : pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'robotframework-ride==2.0a1

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I use Mac and I have python2.7.10, wxpython 3.0.2.0_1. Frankly said, it used to work but after I try "brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python". I can't run ride.py with error below.

Although I try to move back to python2.7.10 as current (instead of python3.x)

Error is still as below. Could here suggest me pls.

```
$ ride.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ride.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('robotframework-ride==2.0a1', 'ride.py')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'robotframework-ride==2.0a1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have installed RIDE (and most probably so for the Robot Framework itself), that was done for python2. Installing python3 will **not** copy all your installed packages - those are two separate programs, as far as the OS and the Python installs are concerned.
This is the reason you see the error in python3.

As to why it is now not present in python2 - I myself can't be sure; when you have copied over the python3 binary to the python one, that may have messed up the environment a bit. This is usually done with symlinks, not with binary copy; you did it for the `python` one, but `pip` for instance most probably still points to python2's.

What I would do is to try un-installing robotframework and RIDE in python2, and then `pip install` them in both the python2 and python3 interpreters.

Comment: Thanks Todor Minakov at least.

It was my confuse that previously I had this all working because I run ride.py under folder robotframework-ride-1.7.3.1 specifically. => Also now I have it works by using this.

I just realized that I can't run ride.py everywhere, although today I just repeat installed 'sudo -H pip robotframework-ride' already. But still can't execute ride.py with error above. 

I'm ok for now : ).